# How to create an expression at runtime for use in GroupBy() with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am building a new extension method which will dynamically be able to group query results from Entity Framework.

I have been able to build dynamic "where" expressions using LinqKit, but this seems to be a different animal.

Intended usage of new extension method:

```
var results = entities.GroupBy("someFieldName").ToList();
```

Extension method definition:

```
    public static IQueryable<IGrouping<object, TEntity>> GroupBy<TEntity>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
        string fieldName) 
        where TEntity : class, IDataEntity
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
        {
            return new List<IGrouping<object, TEntity>>().AsQueryable();
        }

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
        var fieldXExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, fieldName);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(
            Expression.Convert(fieldXExpression, typeof(object)), // throws error when using EF
            parameter);
        return source.AsExpandable().GroupBy(lambda);
    }
```

I need to use `Expression.Convert(...)` because when I was testing using linqTOobjects, the code failed when the column was a `int32`. So I needed to manually convert the column to object and it worked great.

Now that I'm testing it with EF entities, I guess that EF is trying to translate the convert to equivalent SQL, which of course I know doesn't exist.

The error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

Is there a way to generate an expression suitable for GroupBy at runtime that is also compatible with EF?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: The Linq to Entities query provider needs to know the type of the property by which to group; you need to add a generic type parameter to the method call, which you will have to specify explicitly and would probably defeat the purpose of using the property name in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I needed by using Dynamic Linq. I created an extension method called ListGroupKeys:

```
    public static List<object> ListGroupKeys<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string fieldName)
        where TEntity : class, IDataEntity
    {
        var results = source.GroupBy(fieldName, "it").Select("new (KEY as Group)");

        var list = new List<object>();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var type = result.GetType();
            var prop = type.GetProperty("Group");

            list.Add(prop.GetValue(result));
        }

        return list;
    }
```

This allowed me to get the group key values for use in subsequent queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't group by values typed as `object` in Entity Framework, unfortunately. I think there are two alternatives: you can go with returning an `IQueryable` (non-generic) object from the method, which will work if you're doing something like databinding to the result, but isn't good for much else. This allows you to ignore the type of the property you are grouping by.

```
public static IQueryable GroupBy<TEntity>(
    IQueryable<TEntity> source,
    string fieldName) 
    where TEntity : class, IDataEntity
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
    {
        return new List<IGrouping<object, TEntity>>().AsQueryable();
    }

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, fieldName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

    var groupExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                        .First (x => x.Name == "GroupBy")
                        .MakeGenericMethod(new[]{ typeof(TEntity), propertyAccess.Type }),
        source.Expression,
        lambda);

    var result = source.Provider.CreateQuery(groupExpression);
    return result;
}
```

The `IQueryable` returned from this method will be of the right type (if `fieldName` referred to an `int` property, you could cast the result to `IQueryable<IGrouping<int,TEntity>>`), but it'll be difficult to write code which can take advantage of this fact, and you won't be able to cast it to `IQueryable<IGrouping<object,TEntity>>` if `fieldName` is an `int`, because covariance doesn't work for value types.

The other option is only available if you know the type of the property from the calling location, so that you can provide the type of the grouping key in the method arguments (this is the only way you'll be able to get back a properly typed, generic IQueryable):

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TProperty,TEntity>> GroupBy<TEntity, TProperty>(
    IQueryable<TEntity> source,
    string fieldName) 
    where TEntity : class, IDataEntity
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
    {
        return new List<IGrouping<TProperty, TEntity>>().AsQueryable();
    }

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, fieldName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>(propertyAccess, parameter);

    var result = source.GroupBy (lambda);
    return result;
}
```